# How can I make some attributes required in AWS Cognito while creating a user?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

E.g. I want to create a user, but I need a phone number to be required, but the AWS Cognito method `AdminCreateUser` lets me add a new user without a phone number. How can I change it?
Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make any standard attributes required while creating the user pool.

If you use AWS console, while creating the user pool -> Attributes section you can configure which attributes are required.

If you use AWS CLI then you can do while creating the user pool,

```
aws cognito-idp create-user-pool --pool-name MyUserPool --schema Name=phone_number,Required=true
```

Once the User pool is created, you can't change this.